# insert image in dompdf html table

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I want to create below type of layout in my DOM pdf. I tried to use css, but it's not working properly. Here i upload the expected output screenshot. Any help?

```
<div class="gallery" style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:5px;">
        <div style="width:350px; height:300px; min-height:300px;"><img src="https://ec2-54-183-156-161.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/images/1.png" style="height:300px;width:350px;"></div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=2 style="padding:5px;">
        <div style="width:720px; height:500px; min-height:500px;"><img src="https://ec2-54-183-156-161.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/images/1.png" style="height:500px;width:720px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:5px;">
        <div style="width:350px; height:300px; min-height:300px;"><img src="https://ec2-54-183-156-161.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/images/2.png" style="height:300px;width:350px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: layout]

Comment: Why are you using table's any specific reason?

Comment: Define "not working". Some CSS properties are redundant, such as `min-height: 300px` and some can use shorthand, e.g. `padding: 0 15px`. Also, does the `gallery` class have any CSS properties? More, `rowspan` attribute should be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the style, your images have a problem. A part of them is transparent and no matter what you do, they don't fill the table cell. Here's your code with minor changes and different photos:

```html
<div class="gallery" style="padding: 0 15px 0 15px;">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
                                <div style="width: 350px; min-height: 244px;">
                                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/350/244/nature" ></div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2" style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
                                <div style="width: 720px; height: 500px; min-height: 500px;">
                                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/720/500/nature" ></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
                                <div style="width: 350px; min-height: 244px;">
                                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/350/244/nature" ></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Grid Layout is very flexible and suitable for doing such tabular job. Seems this concept comes from Java Swing GridBagLayout . Hope this could help